# How can I subclass numbers.Number so that an instance receives an initial value?

Tags: python, numbers, subclass

I am playing with Peter Norvig's small implementation of Lisp/Scheme in python (https://norvig.com/lispy2.html).  I've created Python classes for LispAtom, LispConsObj, etc.

For consistency, I thought would create a class named LispNumber, that subclasses numbers.Number.  And I thought that I should write an `__init__()` function to reject non-numeric arguments.

```
class LispNumber(numbers.Number):
""" 
LispNumber relies entirely on Number services.
""" 
    def __init__(self, thing):
        if isinstance(thing, numbers.Number):
            self._value = thing
        else:
            raise(TypeError, "'{thing}' is not a Number")
```

This works as is, but it means that there is a new field, "_value", that is no good to anybody.

Also, the constructor for numbers.Number() doesn't take an argument.  So I don't know how to use super() here.

*The answer is probably in the docs somewhere, but I couldn't find anything*

I also thought that class LispNumber could possibly have no code at all, and just be a wrapper around numbers.Number.

```
class LispNumber(numbers.Number):
    pass
```

So that the concrete classes like int() and float() could do their own checking.  However, I still don't know how to get the initial value into the instance object.

Comment: There's pretty much no good reason to subclass `numbers.Number`, and that whole module should probably be deprecated

Comment: It is possible to subclass numbers.Number.  How would I get an object of that type to receive an initial value?

Comment: I want a LispNumber instance to function just like a Python number does, with out having to reference `_value`:
if lnA and lnB are two LispNumber instances, I want this to work as expected.

    lnA + lnB

This may be a stupid idea.  But I know it is possible to subclass the concrete classes like complex and float.  How would a subclass of complex handle initializatiion?

Comment: I mean, the *implementation* can reference `_value`, but that isn't part of the public API. Not sure exactly how you expect this to work. You understand, `float` and `int` are referencing internal representations (for `float` it's just a thin wrapper around a C double, for `int`, it's an array representing an integer (since python `int` object's are arbitrarily sized)

Comment: But again, `numbers.Number` is pretty useless, and has pretty much been abandoned albeit not formally deprecaated

Comment: Perhaps, you just want to subclass `float` or `int` directly

Comment: *...there is a new field, "_value", that is no good to anybody...* What is it you're expecting to happen? Number is nothing more than a base class with no methods or fields. It appears it's sole function is to provide a common ancestor for all concrete numbers so that your code may use `isinstance(x, Number)`.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code, and that answered my question.  numbers.Number is an empty class, and is only a superclass of the rest of the number-types in the tower.

The practical value at runtime is that it is possible to do

`if isinstance(x, numbers.Number):`

and that can be useful.